# "/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/nls_lang.sh not found" when opening a terminal

Tags: command-line

I open my terminal, and at the top I see this

```
(bash: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/nls_lang.sh: No such file or directory)
```

What should I do about it ?

Answer (score 4):

That's an Oracle install environment. Do you have Oracle installed?
You may wish to uninstall Oracle completely if you haven't..

If you still wish to fix login issue/warning message:

*Comment out* or remove any references to Oracle: Look for `$ORACLE_HOME` (and that path in your question) or any call to that script/file nls_lang.sh in your shell files. Basically, you need to remove anything related to Oracle paths/environment and scripts.

Check/edit:

```
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
/etc/bash.bashrc
```

The last one is global bash settings. Be careful.
*Comment out* (by placing a `#` at the start of the line) or remove reference(s) / Save.
Log out. Log in. Message should be gone.